# Using a NuGet package in Visual Studio with Unreal Engine 4

Tags: visual-studio, nuget-package, unreal-engine4

I have installed the Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary package using the by clicking on Manage NuGet Packages, however when I include the header ''' #include <wil/com.h> ''' & compile, it seems that it can't find it so it shows an error message.

Is there a way to make any package work in a UE4 C++ project ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you using Unreal Engine source? If so, you could try right clicking the uproject file and selecting "Generate Visual Studio project files". I've also found with NuGet and Unreal Engine, from my experience at least, that I've had to manually add the NuGet package to the project. Adding it through Visual Studio never worked for me personally.

Comment: @ChrisGong So you're recommending to install the NuGet then generate visual studio project files & this fixes it?

Comment: @ChrisGong How do you manually add the NuGet package to the project?

Comment: Have you tried this solution: https://forums.unrealengine.com/t/includes-using-nuget-package-wont-work/141654/3